# How do I install H2?

Tags: android, h2

I'm new to Android development.

I'm porting a PC application to RealWear's HMT1 Android device. I don't want to rewrite my code, so I'm going to try using Hibernate with H2db, both of which SHOULD work on Android.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any instructions on how to install H2 on Android. H2 is a .jar file, and so far I've only worked with APK's through Android studio.

How do I install H2 on Android?

Comment: You can't install a jar file as an application on android.  You can use one as a library, but that would require you linking it into your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment above, H2 can't be installed on Android as is. I suppose one could take the source code and recompile it for Android but the cost in time and aggravation outweigh the benefits.

Nor can Hibernate be easily used, especially its JPA implementation. Hibernate looks for connection/configuration information in the META-INF directory of the .jar file. I have no idea if such a directory exists or can be placed in an APK such that Hibernate can find it. Moreover, the Dalvik VM has significant differences from Oracle's Java VM, and much of Hibernate's functionality may not even be available on Android.

I had chosen Java for development because of its "Write Once, Run Anywhere" philosophy, but Google seems to have rejected that philosophy. It seems to be "Write Once, Run Anywhere But Android, Where You Have To Write It Again."

Answer (score 0):

add graddle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.196'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.196'
}
```

h2 works perfectly in Adnroid, just add the dependency to gradle.app.
Then you must indicate on what database you are going to work:

```
    try{
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){System.out.println(e);}

    try{
        CONN_STR = "jdbc:h2:/data/data/com.example.example/data/dbfile;FILE_LOCK=FS;PAGE_SIZE=1024;CACHE_SIZE=8192";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STR);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for our answer, but it's really not helpful without any explanation. Please update your answer with some explanation of how this solves the problem.